# postgres window function trebles query time

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgres 10, and have the following query

```
select 
    count(task.id) over() as _total_ ,
    json_agg(u.*) as users, 
    task.* 

    from task  
        left outer join taskuserlink_history tu on (task.id = tu.taskid) 
            left outer join "user" u on (tu.userId = u.id) 

    group by task.id offset 10 limit 10;
```

this query takes approx 800ms to execute

if I remove the `count(task.id) over() as _total_ ,` line, then it executes in 250ms

I have to confess being a complete sql noob, so the query itself may be completely borked

I was wondering if anyone could point to the flaws in the query, and make suggestions on how to speed it up.

The number of `tasks` is approx 15k, with an average of 5 `users` per task, linked through `taskuserlink`

I have looked at the pgadmin "explain" diagram

[image]

but to be honest can't really figure it out yet ;)

the table definitions are

`task` , with `id` (int) as primary column

`taskuserlink_history`, with `taskId` (int) and `userId` (int) (both as foreign key constraints, indexed)

`user`, with `id` (int) as primary column

the query plan is as follows

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=4.74..12.49 rows=10 width=44) (actual time=1178.016..1178.043 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=3731, temp read=6655 written=6914
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=4.74..10248.90 rows=13231 width=44) (actual time=1178.014..1178.040 rows=10 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=3731, temp read=6655 written=6914
         ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=4.74..10083.51 rows=13231 width=36) (actual time=0.417..1049.294 rows=13255 loops=1)
               Group Key: task.id
               Buffers: shared hit=3731
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=4.74..9586.77 rows=66271 width=36) (actual time=0.103..309.372 rows=66162 loops=1)
                     Join Filter: (taskuserlink_history.userid = user_archive.id)
                     Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1182904
                     Buffers: shared hit=3731
                     ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.58..5563.22 rows=66271 width=8) (actual time=0.044..73.598 rows=66162 loops=1)
                           Merge Cond: (task.id = taskuserlink_history.taskid)
                           Buffers: shared hit=3629
                           ->  Index Only Scan using task_pkey on task  (cost=0.29..1938.30 rows=13231 width=4) (actual time=0.026..7.683 rows=13255 loops=1)
                                 Heap Fetches: 13255
                                 Buffers: shared hit=1810
                           ->  Index Scan using taskuserlink_history_task_fk_idx on taskuserlink_history  (cost=0.29..2764.46 rows=66271 width=8) (actual time=0.015..40.109 rows=66162 loops=1)
                                 Filter: (timeend IS NULL)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 13368
                                 Buffers: shared hit=1819
                     ->  Materialize  (cost=4.17..50.46 rows=4 width=36) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=19 loops=66162)
                           Buffers: shared hit=102
                           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on user_archive  (cost=4.17..50.44 rows=4 width=36) (actual time=0.050..0.305 rows=45 loops=1)
                                 Recheck Cond: (archived_at IS NULL)
                                 Heap Blocks: exact=11
                                 Buffers: shared hit=102
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_unique_username  (cost=0.00..4.16 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=46 loops=1)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=1
                                 SubPlan 1
                                   ->  Aggregate  (cost=8.30..8.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=45)
                                         Buffers: shared hit=90
                                         ->  Index Scan using task_assignedto_idx on task task_1  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=45)
                                               Index Cond: (assignedtoid = user_archive.id)
                                               Buffers: shared hit=90
 Planning time: 0.989 ms
 Execution time: 1191.451 ms
(37 rows)
```

without the window function it is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=4.74..12.36 rows=10 width=36) (actual time=0.510..1.763 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=91
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=4.74..10083.51 rows=13231 width=36) (actual time=0.509..1.759 rows=10 loops=1)
         Group Key: task.id
         Buffers: shared hit=91
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=4.74..9586.77 rows=66271 width=36) (actual time=0.073..0.744 rows=50 loops=1)
               Join Filter: (taskuserlink_history.userid = user_archive.id)
               Rows Removed by Join Filter: 361
               Buffers: shared hit=91
               ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.58..5563.22 rows=66271 width=8) (actual time=0.029..0.161 rows=50 loops=1)
                     Merge Cond: (task.id = taskuserlink_history.taskid)
                     Buffers: shared hit=7
                     ->  Index Only Scan using task_pkey on task  (cost=0.29..1938.30 rows=13231 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.031 rows=11 loops=1)
                           Heap Fetches: 11
                           Buffers: shared hit=4
                     ->  Index Scan using taskuserlink_history_task_fk_idx on taskuserlink_history  (cost=0.29..2764.46 rows=66271 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.081 rows=50 loops=1)
                           Filter: (timeend IS NULL)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 11
                           Buffers: shared hit=3
               ->  Materialize  (cost=4.17..50.46 rows=4 width=36) (actual time=0.001..0.009 rows=8 loops=50)
                     Buffers: shared hit=84
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on user_archive  (cost=4.17..50.44 rows=4 width=36) (actual time=0.040..0.382 rows=38 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: (archived_at IS NULL)
                           Heap Blocks: exact=7
                           Buffers: shared hit=84
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_unique_username  (cost=0.00..4.16 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=46 loops=1)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=1
                           SubPlan 1
                             ->  Aggregate  (cost=8.30..8.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=38)
                                   Buffers: shared hit=76
                                   ->  Index Scan using task_assignedto_idx on task task_1  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=38)
                                         Index Cond: (assignedtoid = user_archive.id)
                                         Buffers: shared hit=76
 Planning time: 0.895 ms
 Execution time: 1.890 ms
(35 rows)|
```

Comment: We don't know your table definitions. You do.

Comment: In addition, we'd need output from `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT ...`. Text please, no screenshots.

Comment: thank you for the comments - have added the details as requested to the question

Answer (score 0):

I believe the LIMIT clause is making the difference. LIMIT is limiting the number of rows returned, not neccessarily the work involved:

- Your second query can be aborted early after 20 rows have been constructed (10 for OFFSET and 10 for LIMIT).
- However, your first query needs to go through the whole set to calculate the count(task.id).

Not what you were asking, but I say it anyway:

- "user" is not a table, but a view. That is were both queries actually get slower than they should be (The "Materialize" in the plan).
- Using OFFSET for paging calls for trouble because it will get slow when the OFFSET increases
- Using OFFSET and LIMIT without an ORDER BY is most likely not what you want. The result sets might not be identical on consecutive calls.